# jQuery returns true even when false with select list duplication

Tags: jquery, selectlist

I'm pretty new to jQuery. And am stuck with this, I'm trying to find duplicates in a select list box upon a mouse click. If true it will alert the user, if false it will append the new value and text. However, the function findDuplicates(aVal) when called it always returns true. I tried stepping into the code, the function itself works, but when it went into jQuery script (1.7.2), it becomes true. May be I am doing something wrong? Thanks in advance!

Here's the code:

```
    function findDuplicates(aVal) {
        $("#listBoxAllergy option").each(function (i){
            var isDuplicate = false;
            if ($.trim(aVal) == $(this).val()) {
                isDuplicate = true;
            }
            return isDuplicate;
        });
    };

    $("#btnAddAllergy").on("click", function () {
        var allergy = $("#autoComAllergy").val();
        if (findDuplicates(allergy))
            alert("The allergy is already in the list");
        else
            $("#listBoxAllergy").append("<option value='" + allergy + "'>" + allergy + "</option>");
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***First,*** there are no `.value()` method in jQuery.

`.value()` should be `.val()`.

***Second,*** you should not `return isDuplicate;` inside the `.each` callback, move it outside.

```
function findDuplicates(aVal) {
    var isDuplicate = false;
    $("#listBoxAllergy option").each(function (i){
        if ($.trim(aVal) == $(this).val()) {
            isDuplicate = true;
            return false; // here return false let stop the each.
        }
    });
    return isDuplicate;
};
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change value() to val(), I was using a third party ui. But yes, moving return out helped me, I feel so stupid now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
function findDuplicates(aVal) {
    var isDuplicate = false;
    $("#listBoxAllergy option").each(function (i){            
        if ($.trim(aVal) == $(this).val()) {
            isDuplicate = true;
        }            
    });
    return isDuplicate;
};
```

Try this one

Comment: Use val() method. Or this.value.

Comment: You should use `this.value`, there is no reason to ever write `$(this).val()`.

Answer (score 0):

In your comparator function I would go with strict equality (===) instead of just equality (==) although that isn't the source of the issue.

There is no `value()` method in jQuery, it is `val()` instead